# docker run behaves differently when run through alias then docker run

Tags: git, docker, alias, zshrc

In my .zshrc file I have an alias `alias dra="sudo docker run ansible:2.2"` so when I run `dra` in the terminal the docker container has problems with pulling a git repository `fatal: unresolved deltas left after unpacking fatal: unpack-objects failed`.
However when I run `sudo docker run ansible:2.2` directly from the Terminal everything works nice and the `git pull` part works. The same good behavior I get when I run the `git pull` from within the docker container. I know here are a lot of seemingly unconnected pieces. So if someone just gives me a hint what rabbit hole to dive into that would already help me.

Answer (score 0):

The problem doesn't appear anymore. So unclear, I think it was related to some issues in the git history. How this is effecting aliases is beyond me.